# Why python can calculate dot product with different number of rows

Tags: python, dot-product

Why we can calculate the matrix and vectors with different number of rows and columns.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
y = np.array([5,6])
    
print(x@y)
print(y@x)
```

I couldn't understand why both xy and yx works in this code?

Answer (score 1):

The key facts are:

1. The matrix multiplication `A @ B` requires the number of columns in A to be the same as the number of rows in B.
2. numpy matrix multiplication will "promote" a 1-D array to a matrix ([documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html)). If the 1-D array is the first arg of the multiplication, "it is promoted to a matrix by prepending a 1 to its dimensions": i.e. it becomes a (1,N) matrix. If the 1-D array is the second arg, "it is promoted to a matrix by appending a 1 to its dimensions": i.e. it becomes an (N,1) matrix.

Applying these facts to your examples shows how both of them are valid:

`x @ y`: `y` is promoted to (2, 1). `x` has 2 columns, promoted `y` has 2 rows, so we're good.

`y @ x`: `y` is promoted to (1, 2). Promoted `y` has 2 columns, `x` has 2 rows, so again that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

`y` is 1-dimensional, and so NumPy [broadcasts the arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and does whatever is compatible. If you look at `y.shape`, you'll get a single-element tuple `(2,)`. If you change the definition of `y` to `y = np.array([[5, 6]])`, `y.shape` is instead `(1, 2)`, i.e., 1 row and 2 cols. In that case, the first matrix multiply will not work.